# NodeJS server failed to load JavaScript modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, import, routes

SO citizens. I'm using Node.js with Express.js for the server side of web application. And I often encounter problem when webserver is trying to bind references from the source code.
The structure of my app is:

```
src/
  - static/
     - calendar.js
     - client.js
     - planner.js
     - index.html
  - utils/
     - planListItem.js
     - selectedDates.js
  - index.js
  - server.js
```

**In index.js**

`import app from "./server.js"`

**In server.js**

I register an endpoint "/" with callback function that sends back an `html` file via `res.sendFile()` function passing in absolute path to `index.html`.

**Inside index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
     ...
     <script type="module" src="./client.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Server successfully load scripts so far. But then

**client.js**

```
import { initCalendar } from "./calendar.js"
```

**calendar.js**

```
import Planner from "./planner.js";
import selectedDays from "../utils/selectedDates"
```

**planner.js**

```
import {PlanListItem} from "./../utils/planListItem.js";
```

Enough with the structure:)

The problem is, I suppose, in how **Express** is routing static files, because source code reference were checked 1000 times and are correct.

To defend myself from sully suggestions, I added the following script inside **server.js** beforehand `app.use(express.static("src/static"))`. Which was supposed to help serving scripts. But unfortunately browser responds [image]

It's obvious that Node can't find `selectedDates.js` and `planListItem.js` in utils/. What should I do to make Node find this files???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to serve `utils`, too. You can add

```
app.use('/utils', express.static("src/utils"))
```

after

```
app.use(express.static("src/static"))
```

All paths inside the HTML document are evaluated on the browser. The browser sends a request for each import. You server has to handle these requests.